# Trying to convert an animation from css3 to jquery, reaching walls everywhere

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-transitions

Hi there I am trying to convert the following css3 animation to jquery but not having much luck:

```
    .portfoliobox .rollover
{
    height: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/rolloverbg.png);
    margin-top: 220px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.portfoliobox:hover .rollover
{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 100px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The effect can be viewed here: http://www.astwood.co.uk/testsite/wordpress/

Could anybody help me out?

EDIT: the code I already tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    $('.portfoliobox').hover(function(){  
        $(".rollover", this).stop().animate({margin-top:'220px'},{queue:false,duration:160});  
    }, function() {  
        $(".rollover", this).stop().animate({margin-top:'100px'},{queue:false,duration:160});  
    });  

});
```

Comment: where is jQuery code that you tried?

Comment: Edited the post with the code already tried. It broke all the other scripts on the page and didn't work.

Comment: `{margin-top:'220px'}` is invalid syntax, your code won't compile, it could be `{"margin-top":'220px'}`, or `{marginTop: '220px'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the desired effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/tHDa4/

```
$('.portfoliobox').hover(function () {
  $(".rollover").stop().animate({ marginTop: '80px' }, 160);
}, function () {
  $(".rollover").stop().animate({ marginTop: '300px' }, 160);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

margin-top should say marginTop... that said, I tried what you have there out in a fiddle and it does some FUNKY stuff.

```
$(".rollover").stop().animate({marginTop:'220px'},{queue:false,duration:160});
```

Also, I took out the "this" because it was making jsfiddle nuts.

http://jsfiddle.net/MatthewDavis/qDnC7/3/